# Como colocar CSS em mais de um LI (lista/html)

Tags: html, css

boa tarde.
Estou participando de um curso onde o nosso desafio é fazer um cartão simples de "visita".
Pois bem, quase finalizei, mas não consigo colocar as logos ao lado dos sites.
Primeiro eu fiz a lista UL e tirei as bolinhas no CSS e depois adicionei links com o target blank para a pessoa clicar e direcionar. A questão, como eu coloco as logos separadamente ? tentei criar uma class no `<a></a> e até no <li></li>` para colocar  mas o css não funcionou.

```
<div class="corpo">
        <h1>Mateus Malvezzi</h1>
        <img src="m².jpg" alt="foto mateus">
        <ul>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"  target="_blank"><li>Instagram</li></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mateus-malvezzi-1a0913181/" target="_blank"><li>LinkedIn</li></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/MateusMalvezzi" target="_blank"><li>GitHub</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

O HTML está desse jeito.
E o cartão "finalizado" está assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O único filho direto de uma `ul` só pode ser uma `li`. Vc não pode colocar um `a` como filho direto de uma `ul` como está fazendo. Vc deve colocar tudo dentro da `li`. Tipo: `<li><a href="">link</a> Instagram</li>`.

Comment: Hummm, entendi!

Comment: Provavelmente é por isso que não estou conseguindo sucesso nas logos, certo?

Answer (score -2):

Voce pode personalizar dessa forma também no css, inserindo a imagem para cada li uma imagem:

```css
li{
   list-style: none;
}
ul li:nth-child(1)::before{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   background-image: url('suaimagem');
   background-size: contain;
}
ul li:nth-child(2)::before{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   background-image: url('suaimagem');
   background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Rapaz, muito bom!
Desconhecia alguns conceitos que estão ai, muito obrigado. :)

Comment: Gostei da intenção, mas do jeito que fez não é muito bom pq infla demais o código. O ideal seria criar uma classe genérica com as propriedades comuns e outras 3 onde só muda a imagem do ícone para cada link. Além do que, se o cara resolver mudar a ordem dos links, terá que alterar os índices no `nth-child`.

Comment: Interessante @Sam. Vou verificar a aplicabilidade das duas dicas no meu código.
Em relação ao filho direto do UR, eu concertei, obrigado!

Comment: Com certeza @Sam esse css é apenas uma possibilidade estática, mas dinâmicamente daria para fazer também via javascript.